# What is this game with pegs in holes, jumping and capturing each other?

Tags: identify-this-game

The rules we've guessed so far are:

1. Each move is a peg jumping over another peg in its immediate proximity.
2. The peg that gets jumped over is removed.

The goal is to clear as many pegs as possible. Ideally, leaving just one peg at the end.

Here is a board before before first play-
[image: Unknown board game]

And where does the empty hole start out at? Ive been playing with it at the bottom but it doesn't seem right, because every game can be the same, no?.

Comment: As a small matter of pedantry, this isn't so much a game as a puzzle; you can find more information on the triangular version specifically (a version with a square grid is more common) at http://arxiv.org/abs/math.CO/0703865 .

Comment: Cracker Barrel simply calls it the "[Peg Game](http://shop.crackerbarrel.com/Peg-Game/dp/B0050PMMQA)"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is [Peg Solitaire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peg_solitaire), also simply known as 'Solitaire'. The empty hole is usually located in the center of the board, but for variations and different shaped boards this is not always true. This size board makes it relatively easy to simply memorize a winning series of moves, but for larger boards a player may never find that series and will spend more time exploring possible games even from a single starting position.

Comment: Thanks, it did feel very similar to the Brainvita I used to play.

Answer (score 5):

There are 4 distinct starting positions for the initial hole, considering symmetry:

- vertex,
- centre, and
- side-midpoint,
- side-other (for lack of a more descriptive term)

Try to find solutions for all four starting configurations. You will encounter some similarities between the four.